# @WebService and @Transactional annotations on one class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, soap

I have a Transnational class that I would like to make web service enabled:

I tried:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "searchSth")  
@Transactional 
public class  A{

    public Sth getSth(){
    do sth here...
  }
}
```

but I dint work, I also tried:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "searchSth")     
public class B{
private A a;

public seta(A a){
    this.a =a;
}

public Sth getSth(){
     a.getSth();
    }
}

@Transactional 
public class  A{

    public Sth getSth(){
    do sth here...
  }
}
```

When I run it I get:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cre-remoting' defined in class path resource [remote-application.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22 has neither @WebService nor @WebServiceProvider annotation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.mycompany.crmproject.server.RmiServer.main(RmiServer.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22 has neither @WebService nor @WebServiceProvider annotation
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.verifyImplementorClass(EndpointFactory.java:424)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.getPrimaryWsdl(EndpointImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:231)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter.publishEndpoint(SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.AbstractJaxWsServiceExporter.publishEndpoints(AbstractJaxWsServiceExporter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.AbstractJaxWsServiceExporter.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractJaxWsServiceExporter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585)
    ... 12 more

Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: could you paster the complete stack trace here?

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of your stack trace clearly shows the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cre-remoting' defined in class path resource [remote-application.xml]:
```

Check the definition of your bean called cre-remoting in the remote-application.xml config file. The class you are defining there does not have a @WebService nor @WebServiceProvider annotation.

Comment: It does, above classes are just samples. The class I defined in remote-application.xml is Transactional and its proxy does not have WebService annotation.